# I am trying to center a text with 4 lines, I am looking for a simple solution. The end result is in the image below

Tags: java, arrays, string, text

[Text centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkqH6.png)

This is how I want the text to look after it is formatted.

```
static void printCentered(String text) {
    String[] textArray;
    int maxi = -1;
    textArray = new String[5];
    textArray[0] = "Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass";
    textArray[1] = "sassen auf der Strasse und erzaehlten sich was.";
    textArray[2] = "Da kam ein Mann: Ja was ist denn das?";
    textArray[3] = "Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass.";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        if (textArray[i].length() > maxi)
            maxi=textArray[i].length();
    for(int i=0; i<= 4; i++)
        if (maxi-textArray[i].length()!=0)
        {
            int diff=maxi-textArray[i].length();
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(textArray[i]);
        }

}
```

I am trying to do this just by figuring out what is the largest line and going from there by inserting black spaces from the left.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: No. of spaces before a text should be `(max. length / 2) - (text length / 2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems with your code:

1. You allocated memory for 5 strings but put only 4 values. For same reason it was causing `NullPointerException`.
2. I didn't understand the significance of parameter `text` to the function; it wasn't used anywhere so I removed it.
3. The correct logic for centering text is to find maximum length string, then find length of string to be centered and then calculate number of spaces to be inserted before the string using the following formula:
   `(maxLen / 2) - (textLen / 2)`

Here goes the code:

```
    static void printCentered() {
        String[] textArray = new String[5];
        int maxi = -1;
        textArray[0] = "Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass";
        textArray[1] = "sassen auf der Strasse und erzaehlten sich was.";
        textArray[2] = "Da kam ein Mann: Ja was ist denn das?";
        textArray[3] = "Drei Chinesen mit dem Kontrabass.";
        textArray[4] = "Hello World!";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            if (textArray[i].length() > maxi)
                 maxi = textArray[i].length();
        final int maxiByTwo = maxi / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            final int textLenByTwo = textArray[i].length() / 2;
            final int diff = maxiByTwo - textLenByTwo;
            for (int j = 0; j < diff; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println(textArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Here is the link to the working code: https://ideone.com/QiNIu1